# Angular 2: how I can make relative links with the Router?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

If I've got a route that looks like this:

```
{ path: 'my-component/:foo/:bar', component: MyComponent }
```

Is it possible to create a link that just updates one portion of that URL from within `MyComponent`? For example, instead of:

```
goToNextBar() {
   this.router.navigate(['/my-component/', this.foo, this.bar + 1]);
}
```

I'd like to use something like:

```
goToNextBar() {
    this.router.navigateToRelativeLink({ bar: this.bar + 1 });
}
```

ie, letting the component update just one portion of the URL without having to be aware of the rest.

Comment: I think you need to pass all parameters if they are all from one route. If one parameter is from a parent, then you don't need to pass that. You can use what is explained int the question linked to by Harry.